# select all records that have a certain date: easier way?

Tags: mysql

I'm selecting records that have a certain date in a `datetime` column, but it feels a bit sloppy, and I'm wondering if there's a better way. My query looks like this:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     myTable 
WHERE    event_datetime 
BETWEEN  '2012-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-05 23:59:59'
```

and it works fine. I'm just wondering if perhaps there's a better way to do this in mySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better from what perspective?

One would propose to use `DATE(event_datetime) = '2012-05-05'` but it is terribly inefficient.

So continue using your solution and make sure `event_datetime` column is covered by index

Comment: its indexed ... -- I didn't know about the DATE() function but its apparently not a good choice to use it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function on the column in your where clause.

For example:

```
SELECT   * 
FROM     myTable 
WHERE    DATE(event_datetime) = '2012-05-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do `WHERE date(event_datetime) = '2012-05-05'`, but this way can not use index on `event_datetime`, so if you want to use index of `event_datetime`, use your original way.